# Cauchy distribution maximum likelihood estimator: previous sources?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request

On Wikipedia's page for the [wrapped Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_Cauchy_distribution#Circular_Cauchy_distribution), there's a fixed-point algorithm to calculate the maximum-likelihood estimator using a Möbius transformation in the Poincaré disc that the circular Cauchy distribution can be considered to lie in.

By using the parameterization $\theta=x_0+i\gamma$ on the regular Cauchy distribution and treating $\theta,\overline{\theta}$ as independent variables, the maximum likelihood equation becomes
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\theta-x_j}=\frac{n}{\theta-\overline{\theta}} $$
and there's a similar (likely the same after Cayley transform, even) estimator
$$\theta_{k+1}=\overline{\theta_k-n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\theta_k-x_j} \right)^{-1}} $$
which can also be shown to be a contraction in the Poincaré upper half-plane metric by Schwarz-Pick (and that $z \mapsto -\overline{z}$ is an isometry).  However, the Wikipedia page's sources do not mention these and I've been unable to find a reference showing *either* algorithm, aside from Wikipedia itself.  But, the calculation is simple enough that I'd be legitimately surprised if neither had been done before.  Since I'm not hugely familiar with the statistics literature, I figure this should be aired out.